# Does it make sense to use bindless descriptors for buffer resources?

Tags: directx, hlsl

I am experimenting with bindless hlsl resource binding in my directx12 project and I can see why bindless is useful for binding textures, since you can do the following:

```
DescriptorTable(
    SRV(t0, space=0, numDescriptors=unbounded, offset=0),
    SRV(t0, space=1, numDescriptors=unbounded, offset=),
    SRV(t0, space=2, numDescriptors=unbounded, offset=0)
    visibility=SHADER_VISIBLITY_ALL)

Texture2D textures2d[8192] : register(t0, space0);
Texture3D textures3d[8192] : register(t0, space1);
TextureCube texturesCube[8192] : register(t0, space2);
```

But what about binding buffer resources, such as `StructuredBuffer`s? Since they will need to have a type associated to them, such as `StructuredBuffer<some_struct>`, how would you go about declaring them in HLSL? For example, say you have many different types of `StructuredBuffer`s, do you have to bind them each to a seperate space?

```
struct point_light
{
    float3 position_ws;
    float falloff_start;
    float3 color;
    float falloff_end;
    float3 strenght;
    uint id;
};
RWStructuredBuffer<point_light> sb_point_lights : register(u0, space0);

struct spot_light
{
    float3 position_ws;
    float falloff_start;
    float3 color;
    float falloff_end;
    float3 strenght;
    float spot_power;
    float3 direction;
    uint id;
};
StructuredBuffer<spot_light> sb_spot_lights : register(u0, space1);
```

Or is there a way to do something similar to this (which doesn't work):

```
struct point_light
{
    float3 position_ws;
    float falloff_start;
    float3 color;
    float falloff_end;
    float3 strenght;
    uint id;
};
RWStructuredBuffer<point_light> sb_point_lights : register(u0, space0);

struct spot_light
{
    float3 position_ws;
    float falloff_start;
    float3 color;
    float falloff_end;
    float3 strenght;
    float spot_power;
    float3 direction;
    uint id;
};
StructuredBuffer<spot_light> sb_spot_lights : register(u0 + offset_to_spotlights, space0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to switch between buffers of the same type, dynamic indexing is indeed useful, but as you mention you need to declare resources of the same type (that said, it is the same with textures, I have common use cases for things like Texture2d< uint > for example, so it is not limited to StructuredBuffer).

So yeah, you will have to declare a different array for each typed buffer, which is not super convenient.

If you want to have full dynamic access to your resource (no matter the type), Shader Model 6.6 introduces direct access to heap (code name: ultimate bindless ;)

So you have a global variable called ResourceDescriptorHeap (which represents the currently bound resource Heap)

and SamplerDescriptorHeap (same but for samplers).

Now from there you can do (for example):

```
 int textureLocationInHeap =5;
 int bufferLocationInHeap = 6;
 
 Texture2D myTexture = ResourceDescriptorHeap[textureLocationInHeap];
 StructuredBuffer<float> myBuffer = ResourceDescriptorHeap[bufferLocationInHeap ];
```

You can then pass textureLocationInHeap and bufferLocationInHeap using root constants or constant buffers (as you prefer there).

You don't need to pass descriptor tables anymore (you can of course still use a mix of table/"direct access"

Of course please note that if the resource that you index is not of the correct type (or you have an empty heap slot), you expose yourself to undefined results or driver crash (the second more being more likely).

More information about dynamic resource binding here :

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/in-the-works-hlsl-shader-model-6-6/